# Instagram API media/search endpoint not respecting max_timestamp parameter

Tags: instagram

According to the Instagram API documentation, adding a `max_timestamp` parameter to calls to the `/media/search` endpoint should only return results who's timestamps are less than the `max_timestamp` (http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search). However, this is not always the case.

Take for example the following request:

```
curl 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=51.508515&lng=-0.12548719999995228&max_timestamp=1400700973&distance=5000&access_token=XXXXXXXXXX'
```

I am providing a 'max_timestamp' of 1400700973, but when we look at the results from the API we can see that this is not being respected:

```
{
  "created_time": "1400701017"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701016"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701016"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701010"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701009"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701008"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701003"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400701000"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700997"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700997"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700994"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700992"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700991"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700991"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700988"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700985"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700984"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700980"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700973"
}
{
  "created_time": "1400700973"
}
```

(I used `jq` (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse out the created_times of all of the results)

As we can see, all of the results are actually BEFORE the provided `max_timestamp` parameter. Is this a problem with the Instagram search API, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with timestamps also, and while I cannot remember the exact solution, I think you need to provide both `min_timestamp` AND `max_timestamp` parameters, otherwise you get strange results as you can see. I will provide more detail when I get a chance to go back over my code in this area if you like, but give approach a shot for now...

From memory, I subtracted a certain amount off the max timestamp to use as min_timestamp, then looped over the call until I had the desired number of results (or tried a certain number of times to avoid infinite loops)

Comment: I just tried providing a min_timestamp and it didn't seem to make a difference. Also, according to this similar question from a few months ago, it doesn't make a difference: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348137/instagram-api-media-search-endpoint-return-results-outside-the-time-range)

Comment: Hmm I remember looking at that exact question back when I was searching for an answer. I'll have to get back to you later with a more precise answer

Comment: I got this problem to any help?