# Instagram API /media/search max timestamp issue

Tags: instagram

I am currently working with the /media/search endpoint of the Instagram API. Since this endpoint does not return a pagination link, I implemented an algorithm to fetch more data by using the min and max timestamps. However, somehow the API does not respect the max_timestamp, i.e. when I query for posts in a specific time interval I still get content which timestamp is bigger than the maximum timestamp.
I've done an extensive web search for days and I also found some related posts on Stackoverflow, e.g. [this one about returning results outside the time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348137/instagram-api-media-search-endpoint-return-results-outside-the-time-range) and [this one about non respect of the max timestamp parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792774/instagram-api-media-search-endpoint-not-respecting-max-timestamp-parameter), but none of them provided a solution. Since those 2 examples are only a few months old, I think this is a quite recent problem.

I tried already a lot to understand and solve the problem, so I am wondering if it is due to the fact that I am not using an access token? Or is it another problem? Or is it indeed a problem in the Instagram API?

I'm really looking forward to an answer.

Here is an example to reproduce the problem:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858351&lng=2.29444&distance=5000&min_timestamp=1407192003&max_timestamp=1407278403&client_id=<CLIENT-ID>
```

The response contains the following timestamps:

1. 1407278455
2. 1407278453
3. 1407278448
4. 1407278446
5. 1407278439
6. 1407278423
7. 1407278418
8. 1407278416
9. 1407278410
10. 1407278407
11. 1407278404

Since the specified max_timestamp is 1407278403, all the above are bigger...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that minimal step of pagination is one minute.
For max_timestamps: `1407278400`, `1407278460`, `1407278520` etc. all works well. When you take value bigger than some boundary it takes next.

Remember that Instagram simplifies own lives as they can. Maybe in the future step of pagination will be less.